Flashing and flickering in p5js
I have the following code for a p5js project where I draw 10 eccentric squares and set the blend mode to DIFFERENCE. But the screen starts aggressively flashing and flickering.
let size = 50;
let c = ["red", "green", "blue"];

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
}

function draw() {
  translate(width / 2, height / 2);

  push();
  blendMode(DIFFERENCE);
  for (let i = 10; i > 0; i--) {
    fill(c[i % 3]);
    rect(0 - (i * size) / 2, 0 - (i * size) / 2, size * i, size * i);
  }
  pop();
}


I tried adding push() and pop() but it doesn't seem to make a difference.
Why is it happening and how do i stop it? Also, is push() and pop() doing anything in this example?

You're not clearing the display between your draw calls, so you're differenceing over the last frame too.
Adding a clear() fixes that.
blendMode isn't in the list of attributes saved by push, so in this case push() and pop() do nothing.
In the example below, I moved push() and pop() inside the loop, so they affect the translate() state, giving us a bit of a jiggle.


let size = 50;
let c = ["red", "green", "blue"];

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
}

function draw() {
  let t = millis() / 400;
  translate(width / 2, height / 2);
  clear();

  blendMode(DIFFERENCE);
  for (let i = 10; i > 0; i--) {
    push();
    translate(Math.cos(i * t) * 20, Math.sin(i * t) * 20);
    fill(c[i % 3]);
    rect(0 - (i * size) / 2, 0 - (i * size) / 2, size * i, size * i);
    pop();
  }
}
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.9.4/lib/p5.js"></script>




I saw this trick of adding push() and pop() via this youtube video. might be an older version probably

@shasherazi push() and pop() have been in the API for as long as I can remember. I haven't checked, but I wouldn't be surprised if they've been in since day 1.
